# Help using a CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I have a domain setup as x.abc.com. Now I want to send y.jkl.com to x.abc.com

So I setup a CNAME as follows:

y     CNAME     x.abc.com.

Using WHM. But now when I go to y.jkl.com, it shows:

Great Success ! 
Apache is working on your cPanel® and WHM™ Server

Please help. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect a "ServerAlias" directive will take care of it in your Apache vhost file: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias

Comment: how can i do it using WHM?

Comment: Unfortunately, I wouldn't know as I don't use it personally, but perhaps this page in their docs could be useful? http://twiki.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache3/InsideVHost

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add a host header to Apache so that it knows that x.abc.com should also answer for y.jkl.com.

Comment: how can i do it using WHM?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to WHM, you probably have access to Cpanel

Follow these steps to accomplish a redirection from y.jkl.com to x.abc.com

1. Login to Cpanel account for domain abc.com (usually accessible with http://abc.com:2082 with username and password you've set in WHM for that account)
2. Click on "parked domain" under the domain section on the dashboard
3. Add y.jkl.com to your parked domaim (You need to make sure jkl.com point to your names server, meaning you have access to it)
4. Click on manage redirection
5. Add a redirection to x.abc.com (I assume x.abc.com is already setup to point to a real path on your server)

This setup should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is not expecting inbound requests that have `y.jkl.com` in the HTTP/1.1 "`Host:`" header.

The server is therefore sending back its default web site content instead of your own.